# How to clone a local network git repository

Tags: windows, git, github

I am trying to clone a local git repository in my local network. I did 
`C:\ClonedRepo> git clone \\192.168.0.73\Corporate Files\Git Repo\LMS\`

The LMS folder is the repository.

I also tried
`C:\ClonedRepo> git clone \\192.168.0.73\Corporate Files\Git Repo\LMS.git`

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL6TO.png)

but nothing works.

Any idea?

Comment: Try this `git clone "file:///192.168.0.73/Corporate Files/Git Repo/LMS/.git"`

Comment: It says, You appear to have clone an empty repository.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I have updated my question and an image is attached. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are running these from command prompt? The problem is that there are spaces in the path you are trying to clone. But you can escape them using the quotation marks like this:

`git clone "\\192.168.0.73\Corporate Files\Git Repo\LMS\.git"`

Let me know if this does the trick!